# Is there a way In Android to listen to Audio Volume Changes only?

Tags: android, volume, android-contentresolver, contentobserver

I have seen a few answers to similar types of questions, mostly considering the ContentObserver as its solution. Somewhere on the similar lines as under:

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, new ContentObserver(){...} );
```

But the Content Observer registered for the CONTENT_URI observes for a lot of other changes as well. Although, we can detect if it was a volume change by checking the difference between the previous volume and current volume, which also seems costly where we require an operation to fetch current volume and a variable to store the previous volume which I am looking to avoid.

So, is there a way we can listen for the Audio Volume Change only?

Comment: `SettingsContentObserver` extends `ContentObserver` does this job. Override the `onChange`methode. Place there  the `int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)`...hope that help

Comment: @GGK Yes, I already have it implemented. But my question is that "Is there a URI that we can register the ContentObserver with, that listen only for the Volume change?" The title of this question is: Is there a way In Android to listen to Audio Volume Changes only? - where *only* is the most important thing.

Comment: I see, sorry for misunderstood. I don't know if there is another way like above mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution that works on or above API 16. `MediaRouter` can be used which reports for the Media Route being used along with the Volume Change events.

> Example

```
mediaRouter = (MediaRouter) owner.getContext().getSystemService(MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
setupCallback();
mediaRouter.addCallback(ROUTE_TYPE_USER, callback, CALLBACK_FLAG_UNFILTERED_EVENTS);
```

where setupCallback() is as follows:

```
private void setupCallback() {
    callback = new MediaRouter.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, int type, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, int type, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteRemoved(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteGrouped(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info, MediaRouter.RouteGroup group, int index) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUngrouped(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info, MediaRouter.RouteGroup group) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteVolumeChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
            Log.d("onRouteVolumeChanged", info.getVolume());
        }
    };
}
```

> You can get the VolumeChanged event with a callback method
> `onRouteVolumeChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info)`
> where the volume can be retrieved using `info.getVolume()`